# How do I keep a placeholder for my drop down menu as the first visible value?

Tags: php, html

I don't want it as a label.
Something like this:
[image]

But this 'value' should go away as soon as I click on it once and the actual values should start showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('select').change(function() {
     if ($(this).children('option:first-child').is(':selected')) {
       $(this).addClass('ddplaceholder');
     } else {
      $(this).removeClass('ddplaceholder');
     }
    });
```

```css
.ddplaceholder{color: grey;}
select option:first-child{color: grey; display: none;}
select option{color: #555;} // bootstrap default color
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select class="form-control ddplaceholder">
   <option value="">Type your own text</option>
   <option value="1">example 1</option>
   <option value="2">example 2</option>
   <option value="3">example 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

You need to add some jQuery/See the above example.This is what you want.

Comment: The default values remains as the first option in the drop down. I don't want it to be visible after the first click.

Comment: It wont be visible.Did you put those jQuery and class perfectly? Mine is working fine. Please check once more.

Comment: Now run this snippet above.And see is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want. Don't know why it isn't happening on my system.

Comment: Awesome:) Happy coding .

Answer (score 0):

You can use script in addition to this. You can use remove first child on mouse hover using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable and pre select the default value. Then when user clicks cant re select this option.

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create empty option's

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Vencdor</option>
```

Comment: Want to make the Select Category text invisible on clicking the drop down.